# How to pronounce the last name "Mignotte"?

Tags: prononciation

I was wondering how to pronounce the, assumingly French, last name Mignotte. For a polynomial *p*(*x*) with integer coefficients, there is a bound on how big the coefficients can be on any proper factor of *p*(*x*). This is called the [Landau-Mignotte](https://web.archive.org/web/20201127111919/https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Landau-MignotteBound.html) bound.

- Maurice Mignotte is, I believe, a French mathematician who works or has worked as professor in Strasbourg, the well-known city on the border of France and Germany. This might have an effect on how the last name is to be pronounced.

Apologies if the question is elementary, I have no real experience with the French language. From a specific [text-to-speech online software](https://ttsmp3.com/text-to-speech/French/), the pronunciation appears to be, loosely speaking, `minjot`, ending with a strong, solid 't'. This is also the aspect I am most curious about, as the ending in pronunciation influences how "Mignotte" is to be manipulated in grammar in my native language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not expect any other pronunciation than **/miɲɔt/** by a French person. It is close to (UK) English "**min**<sup>1</sup> **yacht**", the middle "gn" is pronounced like the Spanish **ñ**, close to "ca**ny**on", the name rhymes with "**pot**".

*Mignotte* is not just a proper name but also a noun/adjective in French. Despite being relatively outdated and replaced by *mignonne*, it is still sometimes used and always pronounced /miɲɔt/:

[TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mignotte) [(archive)](https://web.archive.org/web/20201127183854/https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mignotte)

> **MIGNOT, -OTTE**, subst.
> Synon. vieilli ou région. de *mignon* (dont il est la forme anc.). *Viens ça, mignot, dit le poète, à qui sa chaire en vieux chêne donnait parfois des velléités de «vieil langaige»* (A. Daudet, *Jack*, t.1, 1876, p. 282). *Ô ma belle mignotte, mon rêve adoré* (Huysmans, *Le Drageoir aux épices*, p.22 ds Cressot, *Phrase et vocab. Huysmans*, 1938, p. 511).
> ...
> **Prononc.:** [miɳ ο], fém. [-ɔt].

Note: The TLFi seems to confuse /ɳ/ and /ɲ/, the former being unused in French (of France).

This last name origin is [reported to be Burgundy](https://www.geneanet.org/nom-de-famille/MIGNOTTE) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20201127184201/https://www.geneanet.org/nom-de-famille/MIGNOTTE)):

> **D'où vient ce nom ?**
> **Mignot**
> Nom très courant dans toute la France, notamment en Normandie et en Auvergne. C'est un adjectif qui signifie en ancien français joli, gracieux, aimable. Matronyme : Mignotte (Bourgogne).

<sup>1</sup> <sub>The vowel is closer to the one in *m**ea**n*, but is short</sub>

Comment: I'd say *mean yacht*; *min yacht* would have /ɪ/ and not /i/ in the first syllable.

Comment: @PeterShor I though about it but ruled it out because "mean" has a long /i:/ and is (more) stressed.

Comment: @jlliagre Thank you for the answer. I assume your expectation stems from personal experience, being fluent in French? Is there some semi-verified source wherein I could look up the pronunciation of less common names in the future?

Comment: There can not be such a reference because how a name is pronounced can also depend  on regional accents or simply personal preference from the people. It could be that this person prefers for his name to be pronounced with "gn" pronounced like in "agnostique" for example... A noticeable example of that would be with with "W" not being pronounced the same way in France (usually like a simple "v") and in Belgium ("wé"...impossible to explain without writing phonetics, which I can't do).

Comment: @LaurentS. (Leaving aside personal preference) There still could be such a reference, it would just need to be more comprehensive :-)

Comment: Well, technically you're right, but it would just be huge, I guess.

Comment: @jlliagre Thank you for the extra information and links. I will probably accept your answer in 24 h to 48 h.

Comment: Agreed with this pronunciation guide; as an Anglophone I don't think you'll get a closer approximation. Note that the vowel in "yacht" is close enough to work in US English too.

Comment: @LukeSawczak It seems to me AmE way to say it is more like "yaat", but you are right it is still close to the French *-otte*.

Comment: @jiliage I speak a parisian french and I don't pronounce "baignoire" like baiñoire/bainioire, so my pronounciation of Mignotte is /miɲɔt/ not /miɳɔt/ . This phonem is subtle though and I think most of my fellow compatriots don't hear the difference.

Comment: @LoïcDiBenedetto What relationship do you make between the pronunciations of *baignoire* and *Mignotte*? Everyone I know pronounce *baignoire* like *baie noire* so no "ñ" is involved here. In any case, you state your pronunciation is  /miɲɔt/ and that's the one I state in my reply.  Perhaps are you confusing /miɳɔt/ and /minjɔt/ ? The former uses a rare consonant unused in French or English : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_retroflex_nasal

Comment: @jiliagre baignoire is not pronounced like "baie noire" nor baiñoire, example : https://fr.forvo.com/word/baignoire/ you will hear the /ɲ/, it is not an /n/ neither a /ɳ/

Comment: @LoïcDiBenedetto Regardless of how *baignoire* is pronounced or not, what is your point? Is there something you think I should correct in my reply?

Comment: @jiliagre, i think you can't say "the middle "gn" is pronounced like the Spanish ñ", it's very close and certainly undistinguichable for a non native, the phonem gn /ɲ/ is a very specific (and disappearing, we can agree on that) french consonant.

Comment: @LoïcDiBenedetto /ɲ/ isn't known to be French specific nor significantly different between French "gn" and Spanish "ñ": See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_palatal_nasal

Comment: @jiliagre Apparently you're right on this one, I mispronounced the spanish ñ. So yes "mignotte" have to be pronounced like "miñotte" but not like "miniotte". My bad.

Comment: @LoïcDiBenedetto No problem. Spanish makes indeed a difference between *Espa**ñ**a* and *Alema**ni**a*.